# Question mark on filename using fopen

Tags: php, for-loop, curl, fopen

I am having a problem saving a file using fopen. For some reason the saved file has a question mark in the end.

I am attempting to retrieve a list of files from a remote server and download them to my server.
This is the part of my code that does the job :

```
$arrlength = count($reports);
for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; ++$x) {
    $report = $reports[$x];
    $thefilepath = returnfilename($report);
    echo 'the filepath : '.$thefilepath;
    echo '<br>';
    $thefilename = basename($thefilepath).PHP_EOL;
    echo 'the filename : '.$thefilename;
    echo '<br>';
    $localfile = 'incoming/'.$thefilename;
    echo 'local file to save : '.$localfile;
    echo '<br>';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $thefilepath);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    $fp = fopen($localfile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This script returns the following (I've hidden the actual addresses - retain the spaces etc):

```
the filepath : https://example.com.com/xxx/xxx.xlsx
the filename : xxx.xlsx 
local file to save : incoming/xxx.xlsx
```

When on my server I do a ls I get :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 29408 May 17 23:01 xxx.xlsx?
```

There is nothing wrong with the file, when I remove the ? I can retrieve it as normal and open it.
What is this? And how can I do it so it is not added in the end?

Comment: Try copy pasting the random character into Google and it should come up what type of character it is, I've had this problem before it's really annoying :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you're using to name the file has a non-printable character at the end, and `ls` is telling you that there is *something* there, even if you would normally be unable to see it. Strip the character from the string before using it.