# Unexpected output for filename

Tags: php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors' ,1);

//expression to be found in file name
$find = '.5010.';

//directory name
//we will store renamed files here
$dirname = '5010';
if(!is_dir($dirname))
    mkdir($dirname, 0777);

//read all files from a directory
//skip directories
$directory_with_files = './';
$dh  = opendir($directory_with_files);
$files = array();
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
    if(in_array($filename, array('.', '..')) || is_dir($filename))
        continue;

    $files[] = $filename;
}

//iterate collected files
foreach($files as $file)
{
    //check if file name is matching $find
    if(stripos($file, $find) !== false)
    {

        //open file
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handle)
        {
            //read file, line by line
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
            {

                //find REF line
                $refid = 'REF*2U*'; 
                if(stripos($line, $refid) !== false) 
                    { 
                    //glue refernce numbers 
                    //check if reference number is not empty 

                    $refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);
                if($refnumber != '') 
                    { 
                $refnumber = '_'. $refnumber .'_'; 

                $filerenamed = str_replace($find, $refnumber, $file); 
                    copy($file, $dirname . '/' . $filerenamed); 
                        } 

                echo $refnumber . "\n"; 
                    }
            }

            //close file
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I have this code, the output should be the replacement of ".5010." with "*ref*" in the final name, however, when I run the code, it just shows me up to ref not the rest of the file name, I tried it on my computer putty and turns out there's a "?" after the ref number, is there any way I could fix this?

For example; My file is 4867586.5010.476564.ed

After the code executes and reads the file, the output should be: 4867586_SMIL01_476564.ed but instead its: 4867586_SMIL01

And when I checked it out on putty the file name was: 4867586_SMIL01?_476564.ed

Comment: I don't understand, where is the "?" coming from? And what are you trying to achieve?
You should also provide an example of the current directory structure and files, what it is with the current code, and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Okay, please check it out, I fixed it. I think its because I'm using the old version of php, so is there a way that maybe thats the problem, and how to fix it?  @Passerby

Comment: The issue is most likely with this line: `$refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);`. Can you confirm that the .ed file doesn't contain any '?' or invalid characters?

Comment: It's also possible it stops at "4867586_SMIL01" because there's a line ending character after it which is getting replaced with a "?". So `4867586_SMIL01\n_476564.ed` became `4867586_SMIL01?_476564.ed` after your string replace.

Your only real option to gain any further insight into the problem is to provide a full working example with files. Or running through the code via xdebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` in the filename denotes that there's a a [non-printable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287692/4857127) character somewhere in the `refnumber` line.

This is most likely a line-ending character, or something else.
If it's the former, then that can be solved by changing the line:

```
$refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);
```

to

```
$refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);
$refnumber = trim($refnumber); // remove any whitespaces or line endings.
```

If it's the latter, then you'll need to sanitize your `$refnumber` variable using one of the file sanitizer functions available online.

Comment: Hey can you take a look at my other question, if its not too much trouble?